# Pattern.matches doesn't work, while replaceAll does

Tags: java, regex

The regular expression seems to be ok, since the first line line correctly replace the substring with "helloworld", but the same expression won't match in the latter since i cannot see "whynothelloworld?" on console

```
System.out.println(current_tag.replaceAll("^[01][r]\\s", "helloworld"));

if (Pattern.matches("^[01][r]\\s", current_tag)) { System.out.println("whynothelloworld?");}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`Pattern.matches()` expects the *entire* string to match, not just a substring.

Use the `.find()` method of the regex matcher object instead:

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("^[01]r\\s");
Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(current_tag);
foundMatch = regexMatcher.find();
```

Comment: It seems like everybody but me made that blunder when first coming to Java. How I somehow escaped I don’t know.  Somehow I was lucky enough always to use `find`, never `matches`, and this was before I noticed the difference.  I guess it was because I was doing incremental matching in that first Java project, long(ish) ago now.   Still, I consider it a design/user-interface flaw that they did this silly thing.

Comment: Even weirder is Python: `re.match` implicitly anchors the regex to the start of the string (but not to the end) whereas `re.search()` behaves as expected (like `matcher.find()` in Java).

Answer (score -3):

<strike>It can't match again because you just replaced it with "helloworld".</strike>

Edit: sorry, I forgot how this worked.

Comment: `replaceAll` returns a new string - it can't change the contents of an existing string, as strings are immutable.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: OK, it seems my Java is getting a bit rusty. :-p